# Size Pictures in an Excel Worksheet to the Cell Size Using VBA 2

Tags: excel, image

Using VBA I am needing to resize pictures in a range on an Excel worksheet to the actual size of each cell it is in. In other words, I want uniformity in my picture sizes and to be able to sort them within a worksheet. I don't want to change my cell size to fit the picture. I saw something close to this in stackoverflow, but it was for a table, not a worksheet with rows. I already have coding for everything I need except to change an image size to the cell size for each picture in a range of cells. Does anyone have any VBA coding for this?

```
'Option Explicit
'Go through each worksheet, size the cells in the range for pictures
'    Dim WSCount As Integer
'    Dim I As Integer
'    
'Sub SizeFitPics()
'    'Loop through each worksheet in workbook
'    ' Set WSCount equal to the number of worksheets in the active
'         ' workbook.
'    WSCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'    For I = 1 To WSCount
'        Worksheets(I).Activate
'        SizeRowColumn
'    Next I
'End Sub

'Sub SizeRowColumn()
'    Dim R As Long
'    For R = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'        Rows(R).RowHeight = 130
'    Next
'   Columns("L:U").ColumnWidth = 32
'End Sub
```

I received the following answer
'Option Explicit
'
'Public Sub AdjustShapesToTheirCells(ByVal poWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet)
'    Dim shp As Excel.Shape
'
'    For Each shp In poWorksheet.Shapes
'        shp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
'        shp.Left = shp.TopLeftCell.Left
'        shp.Top = shp.TopLeftCell.Top
'        shp.Width = shp.TopLeftCell.Width
'        shp.Height = shp.TopLeftCell.Height
'    Next
'End Sub
'You could then call the sub like so:
'
'AdjustShapesToTheirCells Sheet1

However, the compiler didn't like shp nor poWorkSheet.
I haven't done VBA in a long time and I really don't want to spend loads of time on this, but it would help my current project to inventory my mother and father in-laws stuff they left their children if I were able to show their antiques and collectibles in categories in worksheets.  I already have pictures with each of the items, but I am having to size and resize, etc.  I would like to be able to run my routine above that works to set the size of the cells that will hold the pictures and then run a routine to make the pictures already there fit withing that cell size.
I realize this may be easy for most of you, but my mind doesn't work as great as it used to.  Please give me a routine that will go with the above code and fit the pictures to the cell size.

For further understanding, I have several worksheets which are each named by the category of the items.  For example, one is named Angels, another Furniture, another Clocks, etc.  The first coding above does resize the cells as I want, but I can't get the pictures to fit fully within the cell that contains it.  Some would need to be stretched out and some would need to be smaller.
Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: "the compiler didn't like shp nor poWorkSheet" - what exactly is happening? It's my code and I know it works.

Comment: Right now the compiler is saying there is a syntax error on the following line. 
        AdjustShapesToTheirCells(ByVal poWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet) I can't show all my code in this comment because it won't allow it.

Comment: Just so you know I didn't mean your code did not work, but I couldn't get it to work for me.  Thanks

Comment: If you copy and paste the code as-is from my answer into a new, empty module in Excel, it will certainly compile.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code as-is from your answer into a new, empty module in Excel and it compiled until I called it.  "      AdjustShapesToTheirCells(ByVal poWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet).  That would not compile.  Also what is poWorksheet?  I tried to look up Excel.Worksheet and couldn't find that either.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: AdjustShapesToTheirCells is a subroutine. poWorksheet is an argument you have to provide to it. In your case, to invoke said subroutine, you would write AdjustShapesToTheirCells Worksheets(I), possibly after your call to SizeRowColumn.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure it out.